# Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm using docker-compose to run node.js express app. 
this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
MAINTAINER jorge@valeet.io
# set default workdir
WORKDIR /src/api

# Expose the application port and run application
EXPOSE 3015
CMD [ "node" , "app.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
api:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/src/api
    - /src/api/node_modules
  links:
    - mongo
  ports:
    - "3015:3015"
mongo:
  image: mongo:3.2 
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"
```

running:

docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
I get an error on the the node.js app

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/src/api/app.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

I tried reinstall express, delete all packages, adding node_modules as volume in the docker-compose (the actual setup). I don't know what else to do.
I'm running it on a mac just in case it matters

Thanks!

Comment: The application folder inside the node image is `/usr/src/app`, I think you need to map the volume to there.

Comment: Why are you creating a volume for `/src/api/node_modules`? This volume is  overwriting what is already being mounted in by `.:/src/api`.